# Why "not defined" error returned when rendering an EJS template from ExpressJS app.locals variable?

Tags: express, ejs

ExpressjS Application End-Point (request)

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    db.collection('sys_params').find().toArray((err, sysParams) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        app.locals.landPageRolloverStatus = sysParams[0].landPageRolloverStatus;
        app.locals.ludenourOnlineStatus = sysParams[0].ludenourOnlineStatus;
        app.locals.ludenourContactUsEnabled = sysParams[0].ludenourContactUsEnabled;
        app.locals.ludenourJobsEnabled = sysParams[0].ludenourJobsEnabled;  

        console.log(sysParams)
        app.locals.sysParams = sysParams; 

    });

    res.render('index2');
    next()

});
```

The error is related to the app.locals.sysParams.

```
ReferenceError: /Users/falswaimil/Documents/Project3X/Master/AIRECP/AirECPRetails/online-store/views/index2.ejs:39
    37|          

    38|         <a class="navbar-brand float-xs-right float-sm-left" href="http://localhost:3002/?clang=en"><img src="img/lu3.svg" class="img-fluid"/></a>

 >> 39|         <% if (sysParams[0].ludenourOnlineStatus == "UC" ) { %>

    40| 

    41|             <% if (clang == "en") {  %>

    42|                 <p style="color:red; font-family:Arial Rounded MT Bold; font-size:130%; text-align:center; width: 100%;"><%= __('SiteUnderConstruction') %></p>   


sysParams is not defined
```

However; when I refresh the page, the page is rendered without errors.

Because I am passing an expressJS application-level variable, it should be available on the EJS template across requests.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with properly handling async operations. After using async/await in my middleware, the error resolved.

const readBootstrap = async(req, res, next) => {

```
await db.collection('sys_params').find().toArray()
.then(sysParams => {

    app.locals.landPageRolloverStatus = sysParams[0].landPageRolloverStatus;
    app.locals.ludenourOnlineStatus = sysParams[0].ludenourOnlineStatus;
    app.locals.ludenourContactUsEnabled = sysParams[0].ludenourContactUsEnabled;
    app.locals.ludenourJobsEnabled = sysParams[0].ludenourJobsEnabled;
```